# Layout in different orientations in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, landscape-portrait

I am currently writing and iPad app. I'm pretty new to Auto Layout and I have what seems like should be a pretty straight forward page, but I just can't get it to looks right in both portrait and landscape orientations.

There are three section: an image at the top, a label and a text field near the middle, and a button at the bottom. In both portrait and landscape orientation, I need the three sections to take up most of the vertical space with even padding in between the sections. Obviously in landscape mode the padding with have to shrink, but as long as they are all still proportionate, that's okay. See the pictures below.

I'm looking for some suggestions on how to use auto layout (or anything else really) to make this happen.

In case it's hard to read, the word that the arrows are coming out of is "Same". I'm just trying to indicate that the distances between sections are the same and the distance between the top section and the top of the screen is the same as the distance between the bottom section and the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of ways to accomplish this. One easy way is to enclose the `Label` and `Text` field in a `UIView` just big enough to enclose them. Give it a `centerY` constraint, but adjust its constant to move it up or down from the `center` to where you want. Give the image view a constraint to the top of the `superview`, and the `button` one to the bottom of the `superview`. Give everything a `centerX` constraint. This can all be set up in `InterfaceBuilder`.

Comment: That might work, but it wouldn't adjust the constraints of the image along the top, or the button along the bottom. In the OP's graphic you'll see the constraints along the top & bottom are noticeably different in the two orientations.

Comment: Aaron, you are correct. The problem seems to be getting the system to change the distance between the three sections so they are still proportional to each other. So if they are all 300 px apart in portrait, they should all be 200 px apart in landscape. I'm not sure this is even possible using constraints.

Comment: @user1334007, yes this is totally possible, but it would be easier to do that in code. By using the multiplier and constant parameters, you can have the spacing be different in portrait and landscape.